# Nginx Cache for Azure blob authentication not working

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-blob-storage

Nginx Cache for Azure blob authentication is notworking and getting below error

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Server: nginx/1.23.3
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 04:50:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 408
Connection: keep-alive
x-ms-request-id: fb70e59e-701e-0040-172f-40ef6a000000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-length
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Below is my nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

# Nginx configuration file

http {
    # Define the proxy cache settings
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=static_cache:10m inactive=60m;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <nginx-host-name>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://<my-blob-account>.blob.core.windows.net/nasunifiler64e2bc43-41f8-424d-8f4d-ed85d8fd1ab1-5/;
        proxy_set_header Host <my-blob-account>.blob.core.windows.net;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "SharedKey my-blob-account:<access-key>";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}


}
```

No network issue, I have verified with azcopy and curl (curl request directly to azure blob and worked). My authorization header is correct? or any additional headers need to set?

Comment: Are you specifying your storage account key for `access-key` in `proxy_set_header Authorization "SharedKey my-blob-account:<access-key>"`?

Comment: @GauravMantri, Yes I am giving access key of the storage account

Comment: You cannot use account key as authorization header. Please see this regarding how to compute authorization header: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key.